# Properties of the derivative $\frac{\delta F(\phi(x))}{\delta\phi(y)}$ , where $ \phi(x) = F(\phi(x)) $ is a fixed point problem.

Tags: functional-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

Dear experts I have a fixed point problem of the type:

$ \phi(x) = F(\phi(x)) $, where $x \in \mathbb R^3 $.

$\phi(x)$ is differentiable non-negative function on a given domain. I am trying to find when $\frac{\delta F(\phi(x))}{\delta\phi(y)}$ evaluated at the fixed point $\phi^*$ is greater than zero.

I have arrived at the following result. If the operator is defined as $F(\phi) = \int K(x',x)\phi(x')dx'$, using the definition of a functional derivative

$\frac{\delta F(\phi(x))}{\delta\phi(y)} = \lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac {1}{\epsilon} F(\phi(x)+\epsilon\delta(x-y))-F(\phi(x)) = $

$=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac {1}{\epsilon} \int K(x',x)\delta(x'-y)dx'= K(y,x) > 0 $. If $K(x,x') > 0$ , $  \forall x,x'$.

It seems that the properties of the functional derivative depend on the properties of the Kernel.Is this type of argumentation correct? However, for the general case I can't apply the argument with the functional derivative.

$ \phi^*(x) = F(\phi^*(x)) $, where $x \in \mathbb R^3 $.

Here $F(\phi^*(x))$ is no longer linear integral operator. $\phi(x)$ is again defined to be positive and differentiable. Is it possible in this general case to determine when $\frac{\delta F(\phi(x))}{\delta\phi(y)}$ evaluated at the fixed point $\phi^*$ is greater than zero.

Thanks,

Comment: "the object $\delta F/\delta \phi$ tells us how the functional changes changing the function $\phi(x)$" yes, but you have **infinite degrees of freedom** to change $\phi(x)$. That is why $\delta F/\delta\phi$ (evaluated at a point) is a _linear functional_ over your linear space $M$. My question to you, as I wrote in the very first comment, is what do you mean by a linear functional being positive. Are you using it in the sense that it evaluates to a non-negative number for all non-negative functions?

Comment: I deleted some of my earlier comments in view of your clarification. By translation in the normed linear space $M$, you can assume WLOG that $\phi^* = 0$. Since you are only looking at the functional derivative anyway, you can assume WLOG that $F$ is linear. So your question boils down to "under what conditions is $F$ positive (in your sense above)". If your function space is sufficiently nice, you can say something from the [Riesz-Markov-Kakutani representation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem).

Comment: First of all I would like to thank you for your comments. Actually the $\phi^*$ cannot be zero, because it is a particle density. My guess would be that it is very difficult to say anything in the general case (if $F(\phi)$) is unknown. Moreover, I dont't think I have Hausdorff space. I would like to ask you about your opinion concerning the argument I make on lines 7 and 8. If this is true, it would be quite valuable starting point for me.

Comment: Oh crikeys. I just went back and re-read what you wrote: $F$ is not even a functional. It is an operator $M\to M$. In the case you argued in lines 7 and 8, you defined $F$ as a linear integral operator. But as a **linear** operator you trivially have that $F'[\phi] = F$ (where $F'$ is the Frechet derivative). Hence positivity is a consequence of $F$ being positive.

Comment: I am glad that we finally understand each other :). Now comes the difficult part :). Under which conditions $F’[\phi]$  acting on $\phi^*$ is positive. If $F[\phi]$ ,  $M \to M$ is nonlinear. In the case of the integral equation due to linearity one can prove the positivity, (lines 7 8 of the original message). I also deleted some lines because they were misleading.